Error handling mode on saving application is ignored
I'm having a problem with images with prepended kernel on MacOS. Regardless of :error-handler argument value I provide to the save-application function, if an application fails with an error, I/O becomes blocked (as if it is in :listener mode)
Is there any way to figure out, what I'm doing wrong?
Mac OS 14.4.1
Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.12.2 (v1.12.2) DarwinX8664
Example of "bad" function:
(defun main ()
  (require :uiop)
  (2print (uiop:command-line-arguments)))

save-application call:
(save-application "./heh"
                  :toplevel-function #'main
                  :prepend-kernel t
                  :error-handler :quit)


as a workaround I guess you could add a generic error handler inside main (I can't test on MacOS)

Also drops into a restart handler on linux instead of quitting.

It start to seem, that it might be reasonable to create github issue with this problem
